# Finding max value of a key

Tags: java

```java
public class Task1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        List<String> valSetOne = new ArrayList<String>();
        valSetOne.add("0.00");
        valSetOne.add("0.01");
        valSetOne.add("1.00");

        List<String> valSetTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
        valSetTwo.add("0.00");
        valSetTwo.add("0.01");

        List<String> valSetThree = new ArrayList<String>();
        valSetThree.add("0.01");
        valSetThree.add("1.00");

        List<String> valSetFour = new ArrayList<String>();
        valSetFour.add("0.01");

        map.put("HR3-A1234", valSetOne);
        map.put("HR3-A2345", valSetTwo);
        map.put("HR3-A3456", valSetThree);
        map.put("HR3-A4567", valSetFour);

        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {

            String key = entry.getKey();

            List<String> values = entry.getValue();

            Object obj = Collections.max(values);
            System.out.println("Value of " + key + " is " + obj);

        }

    }
}
```

This is my code, it's working perfectly fine. For key HR3-A2345 I would like to find the minimum value and for the other records I need the maximum value. Can someone suggest me a solution?

Comment: So the title is `Finding max value of a key` and you write `I want to print minimum value`. What is it now? Max or Min value?

Comment: Note: Strings don't sort the same way that numbers do. e.g. `"1.00" > "10.00"`

Comment: You need the minimum value of the values inside the list?

Comment: You're using key and value interchangeably, which makes it very difficult to understand what you want. HashMap is unsorted, so you'll have to account for that too

Comment: Don't forget to highlight your entire code block and press Ctrl+K, or `{}` on the toolbar, or manually indent by four spaces.

Comment: my output should be as below                                                                   
Value of HR3-A1234 is 1.00
Value of HR3-A2345 is 0.00                                                                      
Value of HR3-A3456 is 1.00
Value of HR3-A4567 is 0.01

Comment: For key with HR3-A2345, I want the min value,and for the other records I want max value

Comment: Add that info to your question and not as comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use `if...else`, then I offer to sort collections before put it into the map to place required element first. E.g.:

```
final BiFunction<List<String>, Comparator<String>, List<String>> sort = (values, comparator) -> {
    values.sort(comparator);
    return values;
};

Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("HR3-A1234", sort.apply(valSetOne(), null)); // first element is min
map.put("HR3-A2345", sort.apply(valSetTwo(), Collections.reverseOrder()));  // first element is max
map.put("HR3-A3456", sort.apply(valSetThree(), null)); // first element is min
map.put("HR3-A4567", sort.apply(valSetFour(), null)); // first element is min

map.forEach((key, values) ->
        System.out.println("Value of " + key + " is " + (values != null && !values.isEmpty() ? values.iterator().next() : null)));
```

**Notes:**

1. I can see, that you want to compare double values, but in your example you compare `Strings`! This is not the same. In this case you have to replace `String` with `Double` in your code.
2. If values could not be duplicated, then instead of using `List`, you could use `TreeSet` with required comparator.

**E.g.;**

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Map<String, Set<Double>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("HR3-A1234", valSetOne(null)); // first element is min
    map.put("HR3-A2345", valSetTwo(Collections.reverseOrder()));  // first element is max
    map.put("HR3-A3456", valSetThree(null)); // first element is min
    map.put("HR3-A4567", valSetFour(null)); // first element is min

    map.forEach((key, values) -> {
        if (values != null && !values.isEmpty())
            System.out.format("Value of %s is %.2f\n", key, values.iterator().next());
    });
}

private static Set<Double> valSetOne(Comparator<Double> comparator) {
    Set<Double> values = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
    values.add(.0);
    values.add(.01);
    values.add(1.);
    return values;
}

private static Set<Double> valSetTwo(Comparator<Double> comparator) {
    Set<Double> values = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
    values.add(.0);
    values.add(.01);
    return values;
}

private static Set<Double> valSetThree(Comparator<Double> comparator) {
    Set<Double> values = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
    values.add(.01);
    values.add(1.);
    return values;
}

private static Set<Double> valSetFour(Comparator<Double> comparator) {
    Set<Double> values = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
    values.add(.01);
    return values;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but I want max values for all other keys, which I got and need min value only for key HR3-A2345.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        String key = entry.getKey();

        List<String> values = entry.getValue();

        Object obj = key.equals("HR3-A2345") ? Collections.min(values) : Collections.max(values);
        System.out.println("Value of " + key + " is " + obj);

    }
```

or

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        String key = entry.getKey();

        List<String> values = entry.getValue();

        Object obj;
        if(key.equals("HR3-A2345"))
            obj = Collections.min(values);
        else
            obj = Collections.max(values);
        System.out.println("Value of " + key + " is " + obj);

    }
```

I may have misunderstood your question, but it seems all you need is to compare the key against the one you want to find.